# How to deal with one material is lighted up while baking indirect lighting in eevee and it does not have any shadows on object

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, baking, shadows

I'm making an interior scene in eevee.
I need to bake indirect lighting to get better shadows, but i'm eneding up that scene in general looks too dark, while upholstery material looks too light.

[image]

[image]

If i'm increasing exporsure, sofa gets overlighted

Also, my sofa is animated, so I've applied Irradiance Volume only on static objects (room itself)

I'm using poliigon materials for that scene, but I have been using it for a while already, for similar scenes, and I hadn't had any issues

Does someone have any ideas how to solve this?
That would be a great pleasure to fing a solution

Comment: Hello and welcome. Look into portals to increase light from HDRI coming into the scene.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for you respond! I found out that world color was too dark and I changed it to just white and low strenght. That's kind of the same you're writing about. Thank you!